# Parsing Huge XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a 20 GB XML file that I need to parse using Java. Does any one know how to parse such a big file? The regular file IO operation does not work and throws error.

Thanks

Comment: maybe try using a buffer to read parts of it. anyway 20GB xml sounds like this is a bad usage of xml. plesae explain why is this so big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't be able to parse the whole file at once into a DOM tree or similar, but a streaming approach such as SAX or StAX should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In general, 20GB is something very unusual. The only possible solution is to use some [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) parser, if you can't pre-process the file and split it into some chunks of smaller size. It shouldn't cause any IO errors with files as soon as you could write it.